# "Move to meta" votes not working?

Tags: bug, status-completed, migration, vote-to-close, meta

Despite having accumulated seven "move to meta" votes, [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5387456/how-do-i-know-what-part-of-my-question-was-edited-by-another-user-in-stackoverflo) is rather recalcitrant.

Comment: Seven (or 10, if you go by the final result) is nothing on [33 votes to migrate](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/83748/eeeek-how-does-this-question-have-28-and-growing-close-votes-without-being-cl "Includes two diamonds prior to the actual successful close.").

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Just about to deploy a fix ..... LINQ 2 SQL is obsessed with recompiling the same thing over and over, this is a side effect of a workaround